# SSDT Fails to build Data project after clearing out my TEMP folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

After clearing out my temp folder in an effort to free up some much needed disc space, my Sql Server Data Tools (SSDT) in Visual Studio 2012, no longer builds my data project and Schema Compare is now useless ('cause it's gotta successfully build first). I get the following error message ...

```
Error   187 04018: The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\gstenstrom\AppData\Local\Temp\b3546b57-815f-43e1-92a5-831cd4844026.9.tmp'.
```

OK so the problem is obvious; I have clearly deleted something I needed to keep. However, I cannot replace the file as it's been deleted permanently, so what do I do to fix this issue? I have been astounded as to how little information there is about this out there so far. Any help would obviously be greatly appreciated.

Looking for a Christmas Miracle here ... quick and simple!!! :)

Thank you for your help and Happy Holidays!!

Comment: Can I ask what you did here?  I was in a scenario that also required the clearing of this temp folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just had the same issue. I think you figured this out as well, but just for future reference: restarting Visual Studio should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sometimes we focus so much on the problem that elementary things are forgotten.